# Problem while installing apache2

Tags: apache2

I wanted to install apache and mod_wsgi properly.

When I tried to install apache2 using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed: 
apache2-data
Suggested packages: 
apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom apache2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
apache2 apache2-data
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/247 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,194 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
(Reading database ... 567255 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
WARN: /etc is world writable!
WARN: /etc is group writable!
WARN: / is world writable!
WARN: / is group writable!
WARN: /usr is world writable!
WARN: /usr is group writable!
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9) ...
Enabling module mpm_event.
Enabling module authz_core.
Enabling module authz_host.
Enabling module authn_core.
Enabling module auth_basic.
Enabling module access_compat.
Enabling module authn_file.
Enabling module authz_user.
Enabling module alias.
Enabling module dir.
Enabling module autoindex.
Enabling module env.
Enabling module mime.
Enabling module negotiation.
Enabling module setenvif.
Enabling module filter.
Enabling module deflate.
Enabling module status.
Enabling conf charset.
Enabling conf localized-error-pages.
Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log.
Enabling conf security.
Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
Enabling site 000-default.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
WARN: /etc is world writable!
WARN: /etc is group writable!
WARN: / is world writable!
WARN: / is group writable!
WARN: /usr is world writable!
WARN: /usr is group writable!
```

I am new to this. Can I get any help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to Apache2, it is related to your folders permissions.

Use

```
ls -l /
```

what the rights are for these directories and change them from rwxrwxrwx to rwxr-xr-x using `chmod`

Answer (score 0):

The warnings that you are getting are stating that the directories that you are getting can be edited by users other than admin.

Test apache to see if it works, open a web browser on the machine with apache installed and type localhost into the web address bar and your apache welcome page should come up.

If you need too test it using a different machine than in your apache machine type in a command prompt

```
ifconfig
```

Than enter the inet address into any web browser connected to your wifi network.

Feel free to ask any questions, I run my own apache server so I can help.

Comment: I changed the permissions. Now sudo apt-get install apache2 ran smoothly. But apache2 -v says 'The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin' . So I tried the suggestion. But still apache2 -v says its not installed. What is going wrong here. I am very new to this.

Comment: try opening a web browser and type localhost and press enter and see if i t brings up the apache default page